# cannot check(select) radio button inside a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

In my page I am using custom modal dialog and inside that modal I am using a form. I have put two radio button inside that form but I cannot check either one.

```
<div id="user_modal" class="modal modal__bg" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__dialog">
        <div class="modal__content">
            <h1>User registration</h1>

            <form action="" id="u_register_form">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="Full name" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="w" name="optradio"/>Worker</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="e" name="optradio"/>Engineer</label>
                </div> 

                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" required placeholder="Username">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="u_pwd1" pattern=".{8,}" required placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group submit_btn">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" id="u_register_btn" type="submit" value="SAVE">
                </div>

            </form>

            <!-- modal close button -->
            <a href="" class="modal__close demo-close">
                <svg class="" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 6.41l-1.41-1.41-5.59 5.59-5.59-5.59-1.41 1.41 5.59 5.59-5.59 5.59 1.41 1.41 5.59-5.59 5.59 5.59 1.41-1.41-5.59-5.59z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"/></svg>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by check? refine your question.

Comment: not selecting any button. when i try to click a radio button nothing happen.

Comment: Have you checked your console showing any errors?

Comment: no errors showing, but if i put those two radio button outside the modal, it is working

Comment: this is working fine check this .https://jsfiddle.net/8Lcayu5m/

Comment: then I think probably because of the custom modal class.

Comment: You might running bootstrap or some other framework; the fiddle they shared is just code that's why it is working. Use standard class for this modal and try.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check your console for errors. The code loads fine on its own in a simple notepad .html file. The error is probably before this or with the "radio-inline" class.

Comment: no errors showing in console. i tried both chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

Its working properly i did't change anything ..

```html
<div id="user_modal" class="modal modal__bg" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__dialog">
        <div class="modal__content">
            <h1>User registration</h1>

            <form action="" id="u_register_form">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="Full name" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="w" name="optradio"/>Worker</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="e" name="optradio"/>Engineer</label>
                </div> 

                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" required placeholder="Username">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="u_pwd1" pattern=".{8,}" required placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group submit_btn">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" id="u_register_btn" type="submit" value="SAVE">
                </div>

            </form>

            <!-- modal close button -->
            <a href="" class="modal__close demo-close">
                <svg class="" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 6.41l-1.41-1.41-5.59 5.59-5.59-5.59-1.41 1.41 5.59 5.59-5.59 5.59 1.41 1.41 5.59-5.59 5.59 5.59 1.41-1.41-5.59-5.59z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"/></svg>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```